# How to set periodic task on Django using celery?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, celery, django-celery

My current code:

```
from celery.task.schedules import crontab
from celery.decorators import task, periodic_task


@periodic_task(run_every=crontab(hour=15, minute=55, day_of_week="wed"))
def demo():
    print("testing------------------------")
```

**Setting file:**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ.get('CELERY_BROKER_URL', 'amqp://guest:guest@localhost//')
```

It's not working, am I missing something?

**Thanks In advance**

Comment: did you run celerybeat?

Comment: Yeah, I have run in parallel terminal

Comment: do you have any logs?

Comment: No logs, for this task

Comment: am i missing something on settings?

Comment: show your configs or add more info

Comment: that's all info that i'm using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use the below code, it should be work for you.

```
celery_app = celery("project_name")

@celery_app.on_after_finalize.connect
def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
  sender.add_periodic_task(5.0, demo.s(args))

@celery_app.task(bind=True)
def demo(args):
   print("testing------------------------")
```